# How to get the first element with a specified class using React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I want to access the first element with class "icon".

This is how the DOM looks:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div data-testid="add">
        <div class="info"></div> 
        <div class="action">
            <div class="icon"/> // <== I want to access this 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div data-testid="add">
        <div class="info"></div> 
        <div class="action">
            <div class="icon"/> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the first div with class "icon"?

I have tried:

```
const element  = queryAllByTestId('add')[0].querySelector(
    'div'
  )[1];
```

This gives element undefined.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[getAllBy](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#getallby)

> `getAllBy*` queries return an array of all matching nodes for a query,
>   and throw an error if no elements match.

[queryAllBy](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#queryallby)

> `queryAllBy*` queries return an array of all matching nodes for a
>   query, and return an empty array (`[]`) if no elements match.

[Query Cheetsheet](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/cheatsheet#queries)

[image]

Use the query variant so as not to throw in a test if no matches found, and use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) since `querySelector` returns only the first element that matches, or null.

```
const element = queryAllByTestId("add");
if (element.length) {
  let divs = element[0].querySelectorAll("div");
  // ...get the div node you need
}
```

You can even specify divs with a specific class

```
const element = queryAllByTestId("add");
if (element.length) {
  let divs = element[0].querySelectorAll("div.icon");
  // ...get the div node you need
}
```

Comment: thanks. i cannot use div.icon since the classname is added dynamically as i am using react + typescript..so should go with first option. but then querySelectorAll("div") gives all the divs under the div got by testid..how do i get second div (i.e., action) and get its firstchild (i.e., icon) without using class and something like div[1].firstChild...this doesnt work for me

Comment: @someuser2491 Is there any reason you can't also place a `data-testid` attribute on the icon div for testing? The other options are the boilerplate DOM "walking", or a more specific/targeted query selector, something like "div + div" to select the icon div child of the action div (*Disclaimer: may need to be tweaked*).

Comment: i dint want to add the data-testid. but since its tedious i would add it. so would it be queryAllByTestId('icon')[0] to select first icon div with testid icon?

Comment: @someuser2491 Yes, if the element is `<div class="icon" data-testid="icon"/>, then you can query it via `queryAllByTestId('icon')`. Remember though, it *can* return an empty array so you shouldn't assume to be able to directly array index into it.